# How to prevent preview-latex to manipulate and delete the pdf created by latex

Tags: latex, auctex, pdf, preview-latex

Running latex-preview manipulates and then deletes the pdf created by latex. If skim is open as pdf-viewer the pdf gets sliced into the images created by latex-preview. Running latex again doesn't update the pdf-view in skim. The problem of vanishing the pdf file is already listed on the package homepage https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/preview-latex.html under B.5.2 and B.5.3. There is mentioned as an explanation that Preview-latex uses the filename of the original output file for the creation of preview images. But neither on that homepage nor somewhere else I was able to find a solution in order to prevent this. So how can I prevent preview-latex to manipulate and delete the pdf file?

Comment: What happens if you call `preview-buffer` instead of `preview-document`? As far as I can see that only runs `preview-region` for the full buffer and `preview-region` does not use the master file name. On the other side `preview-buffer` should cover quite much of `preview-document`.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work. A little remaining issue is that I have to first run preview-document otherwise preview-buffer couldn't find preview images. Another solution that also works for me is to use latexmk -outdir="..." to change the output directory in which the pdf-file of the document is saved. This also works obviously in common with preview-document.